# Tukey HSD - can I add an additional data point to each group?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

When computing Tukey HSD I have multiple groups. For a homework assignment, I realized I accidentally included an additional data point in each group, which is the average of the group. Is this allowed?  Is it considered synthetically generated data? Is this bad practice when there is only few data points per group?

Comment: It is synthetic and you should not include it. Now if your sample is "large" this might not make much of a difference, but still...